# Calling javascript function in html page from asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

In my asp.net project I have added a html file. I am displaying that html file using "iframes".  That html file displays google map and contains javascript function. My question is, How can I call those javascript function from code behind???
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the iFrame's DOM element first:

```
var myframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');
```

Then you access it's window element, and call a function:

```
myframe.contentWindow.myFunc();
```

That should work.